# Динамическое программирование Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, комбинаторика, динамическое-программирование

Объясните, как решать задачи на динамическое программирование.

Вот условие:

> Кубик, грани которого помечены цифрами от 1 до 6, бросают `N` раз.
>   Требуется найти вероятность того, что сумма выпавших чисел будет равна
>   `Q`. Входной файл `INPUT.TXT` содержит натуральные числа `N` и `Q`
>   (`N` ≤ 500, `Q` ≤ 3000).

Объясните подробно, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну почему бы самому не найти решение в Гуугл? Сложно. Или лень? А другим не лень пересказывать то, что 100 раз описано, показано, повторено и изучено? Смотрите и запоминайте: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Gqy1saotsU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Составляем таблицу

```
                     Q
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 ...

  1
N 2
  3
...
```

В ячейках на пересечении N-ной строки и Q-того столбца записываем количество разных способов выбросить N костей, чтобы набрать Q очков. Из количества потом можно будет получить вероятность, поделив его на 6<sup>N</sup>.

Очевидно, что набрать 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 или 6 очков с одной костью можно только единственным способом, а 7 и больше - и вовсе нельзя.

```
                     Q
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 ...

  1   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...
N 2
  3
...
```

Теперь заполняем второй и последующие ряды. Допустим, на очередной кости выпала единица, значит на оставшихся `N-1` костях должно выпасть `Q-1`, чтобы в итоге получилось `Q` очков за `N` бросков. Если выпала двойка, значит на оставшихся `N-1` костях должно выпасть `Q-2` очка, и т.д.
Считаем все возможные варианты для `N,Q`

```
M[N, Q] = M[N-1, Q-1] + M[N-1, Q-2] + M[N-1, Q-3] + M[N-1, Q-4] + M[N-1, Q-5] + M[N-1, Q-6]
```

Например

```
M[2, 3] = M[1, 2] + M[1, 1] + M[1, 0] + M[1, -1] + M[1, -2] + M[1, -3]
        =       1 +       1 +       0 +        0 +        0 +        0
```

(несуществующие ячейки считаем равными нулю)

```
                     Q
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 ...

  1   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...
N 2   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  5  4  3  2  1
  3   0  0  1  3  6 10 15 21 25 27 27 25
...
```

Т.е., например, вероятность выбросить 12 очков тремя бросками равна 25/6<sup>3</sup>